# Simple Query Slow In Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Is there anyway to get better performance out of this.

```
select * from p_all where sec='0P00009S33' order by date desc
```

Query took 0.1578 sec.

Table structure is shown below. There are more than 100 Millions records in this table.

```
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sec              | varchar(10)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| date             | date          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| open             | decimal(13,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| high             | decimal(13,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| low              | decimal(13,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| close            | decimal(13,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| volume           | decimal(13,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| unadjusted_close | decimal(13,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

EXPLAIN result

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | price_all | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 12      | const | 1731 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

How can i speed up this query?

Comment: And how fast do you expect it to be? 150ms doesn't sound so bad to me for such a query. How many rows are returned by that query?

Comment: you're complaining because 0.1578 sec is slow?

Comment: @KarimLahlou: `sec` is part of the primary key, so it is already index which you can also see in the execution plan

Comment: Where's the actual problem here? 157 msec to query 100 million rows. If you want something better - get a better HDD and faster + more RAM.

Comment: how about selecting the fields you want? Wouldn't that reduce time? Getting rid of redundant fields that are not needed for the query?

Comment: Maybe sort your data by date after fetching the data?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it will return around 2437 rows.

Comment: just create a covering index on (sec, date desc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you do a `SELECT *`, but you only have an INDEX that contains the columns `sec` and `date`.

In result, MySQLs execution plan roughly looks like the following:

1. Find all rows that have `sec = 0P00009S33` in the INDEX. This is fast.
2. Sort all returned rows by `date`. This is also possibly fast, depending on the size of your MySQL buffer. Here is possibly room for improvement by [optimizing the `sort_buffer_size`](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/25/impact-of-the-sort-buffer-size-in-mysql/).
3. Fetch all columns (= full row) for each returned row from the previous INDEX query. This is slow! see (1)

You can optimize this drastically by reducing the SELECTed fields to the minimum. Example: If you only need the `open` price, do only a `SELECT sec, date, open` instead of `SELECT *`.

When you identified the minimum columns you need to query, add a combined INDEX that contains exactly these colums (all columns involved - in the `WHERE`, `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` clause)

This way you can completely skip the slow part of this query, (3) in my example above. When the INDEX already contains all necessary columns, MySQLs optimizer can avoid looking up the full columns and serve your query directly from the INDEX.

*Disclaimer:* I'm unsure in which order MySQL executes the steps, possibly i ordered (2) and (3) the wrong way round. But this is not important to answer this question, though.